# How do I get the hostname of a connected client in java?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, hostname

I'm writing a server application and I want to get the hostname of the connecting client, how would I go about doing it in java?

`clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName()` keeps giving me the IP address instead of the hostname, what's wrong?

where `ClientSocket` is an `SSLSocket` or `Socket.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`getCanonicalHostName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName%28%29) instead - but read the Javadoc, as this is not guaranteed.  (You're limited to what is registered in DNS, etc.)

Comment: I still got theIP address instead, what gives? I set the hostname on the computer to a particular name but it does not seem to be recognized, I have multiple network adapters, does it make a difference?

Comment: This is likely going to become a networking issue outside the scope of SO.  If you try running "nslookup <IP address of interest>" from the command line, does it work?  If not, you can't expect Java to resolve it for you, either.  When you said you set the hostname on a particular computer - it's not the same computer that you're running this application on, is it?  If not, the IP needs to be reverse-resolvable by the system - using a hosts file, DNS, or another resolution mechanism.